# How do you unstar a level in Super Mario Maker?

Tags: super-mario-maker

In Super Mario Maker you may give levels a star. This indicates you really enjoyed the level and adds it to a special list (essentially your favourites list).

Is there any way to remove levels from this list? (**Un**star the level?) I can't find it in game.

Comment: Well, the thing is... starring other peoples levels unlocks medals on their account, so I'm not sure it would allow unstarring.

Comment: Hmm.. Then they should have a separate favourites menu... I've hit star by accident on the touch screen, and it's also done it just because I commented. (Why aren't commenting and starring separate??) I don't want certain stages in that list... :(

Comment: I don't think commenting and starring are the same thing, because if I remember correctly I've commented without starring a level.

Comment: @Guy Well that's just not true. Every time I comment, even within the level, it automatically stars it. Which is counter-intuitive; What if I'm leaving a criticism?

Comment: @Guy It would be nice to know if there is a way to comment without starring. I've opened a separate question for this here:

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236696/how-to-add-a-comment-without-starring-a-course-in-mario-maker

Comment: I did comment on a game yesterday with critisim, and it does automatically star it... And now I can't even unstar it. What a poor design choice.

Comment: The auto-star on comment is to prevent people from leaving mean/overly critical comments. If you hated a level, then Nintendo wants you to just skip it, not berate the person who made it. They tried to encourage you to do that by tying a star to the comments - so if you really hated that level, did you hate it so much that you were willing to give the guy a star just to tell him how bad it was? Probably not, you'd probably prefer to just not say anything so at least he doesn't get a star for it. lol

Comment: Yeah that's too bad isn't it, but when you get right down to it, does it really matter?

Comment: Turns out that the list eventually starts replacing older entries anyway. So much for saving them forever :/ There's the new website coming out though, maybe that will be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be no way to unstar a level.

Some anecdotal experiences:  [1](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805618-super-mario-maker/72472958), [2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805618-super-mario-maker/72473061)

There is, however, a way to comment without starring a stage.

1. Play (and possibly clear?) the course
2. Go to Course World
3. Press -
4. Select Played Courses
5. Select View Comments on the course you want
   Comment in the Miiverse area.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/3kry8z/theres_a_way_to_comment_on_a_level_without/)

Comment: True, but the complain about un-starring usually occurs when a player tries to leave a negative comment and ends up starring said stage.

Comment: Right, and I'm not claiming it does.  Accidental starring occurs from comments, and this is a preemptive answer before the question comes up.

Answer (score -1):

You can't unstar a level. I've tried it with a few levels I didn't really like after I accidentally starred them or thought about it and didn't like the level. So you cannot unstar a level after you star it. :/

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything not already covered by the existing answer.