# How to add a comment without starring a course in Mario Maker?

Tags: super-mario-maker

When you try to add a comment to a level in Mario Maker, it automatically gives the level a star [which doesn't seem to be undoable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236193/how-do-you-unstar-a-level-in-super-mario-maker). There are times I would like to give a course criticism without rewarding the maker. How can you add a comment to a course without having it automatically star the course?

Comment: It's possible that this was by design, so that commenters are encouraged to leave compliments or comments with constructive criticism, or otherwise not comment at all

Comment: @QuestionMarks I think you are absolutely right. It makes sense to have it that way as I'm sure it helps avoid a lot of potential violations of the miiverse code of conduct.

Comment: Perhaps if you are in the course viewer before playing a level (not directly after clearing the level or while inside it) and choosing the comment button will do it.....I will test later.

Comment: The point of forcing you to leave a star with a comment is to prevent people from leaving mean comments on levels they either couldn't beat or just didn't like. By forcing you to leave a star, you have to think - was the level so terrible that I'm willing to give this guy a star just to tell him how bad it was? Nintendo is betting that you won't, that instead you will just move on without saying anything to avoid giving that person a star.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [this  reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/3kry8z/theres_a_way_to_comment_on_a_level_without/)

```
1. Play (and possibly clear?) the course
2. Go to Course World
3. Press -
4. Select Played Courses
5. Select View Comments on the course you want
6. Comment in the Miiverse area.
```

Comment: Unless the author checks Miiverse, they won't see these comments in game, will they?

Comment: @Jason_c_o - They will still get a notification in game like they normally would. It won't show up in the stage, instead it will work like comments you can leave at the end of the level.

Comment: Note: A course will not be put in your "Played Courses" list unless you either die at least once or clear the stage.  So if you bail out of a stage right away, you will not find it in your Played Courses.